# Idiots guide to getting a django project onto the web please

Tags: django

Help! I think i've gone in a bit over my head. I'm making a website for a friend who has already got a domain/hosting on the website 123reg. Keen to learn them i've been picking up python and django as i go, figured getting it online would be no problem because 123reg supports python (unspecified version).

So far i've been doing everything with the django test-server locally, i went to look into uploading it somewhere as a test and realised there's an awful lot i don't know and even with google its a bit overwhelming.

I found [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) which will help me later i'm sure but right now, could someone help me understand *What is Apache*? I thought the server was the hardware a site was physically hosted on but i can't understand it at all now.. So *i download Apache and then what?* Can i just copy it into the root directory for the website on 123reg? Is their an installer? Will 123reg allow it to "run" or "serve" or whatever word's appropriate or *will there be permissions issues?*

And then once that's sorted there's mod_wsgi to look into, a cursory glance at the installation guide shows commands to be run, which confuses me further as i was not aware that a standard host like 123reg have any sort of inbuilt console window to be run on in which case *how are you expected to execute these commands?*

And another thing I didn't really think through, I'm using the built in sqlite database technology.. How will i be able to install it on my webspace? and then how will that effect my django configuration? or maybe i'll have to change to MySql v5 which 123reg says it supports?

I know these must be idiotic questions, I just wasn't sure where best to ask for help and SO has one of the most helpful and knowledgeable communities around. I did try having a google but everything was a bit overly technical for me.

Comment: Apache *is* the webserver software. It's already running on their machines. Don't try and install it lol, or they will certainly laugh at you.

Comment: Does your friend have a dedicated server or a hosting package that supports Python as CGI scripts? If it's the latter, you won't be able to run Django smoothly.

Comment: go through this tutorial from 123 - how can i upload my website - http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Hosting/FTP-Management-and-Uploading-your-Website/how-can-i-upload-my-website-using-ftp-370/

Comment: @rs. really is it a simple as that folks? ive used an ftp client before but i thought alot more setup would be needed. For example do i just upload my existing .db file? and what about the django framework?  and is mod-wsgi already installed too?

Comment: if your server is shared you cannot install or modify any packages, framework etc, they should be already installed or contact support. Check point number 11 in that link

Comment: @rs. Ah so it's not up to me to install mod_wsgi either? okay thank you!

Comment: Alternative: Use Heroku. I got my project deployed live in the internet in 20 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload a Django site using FTP on a shared hosting provider and expect it to run. You'll need to configure it to run with their installed Apache, including configuration like mod_wsgi.

I very much doubt that 123-reg support this. You are unlikely to be able to run a Django site there. You should look for a more Django-friendly site - I recommend Webfaction.

Comment: Ah i see, i should have done more research! i was recommended it alongside the likes of php and having just copy pasted such a script before i naively figured the upload process would be just as easy. This is pretty  unrelated but i might as well ask, could i do away with the django elements of the website and just continue to use python templates? And maybe store the content that was in the database just in a python class and use that instead? I assume i can do so by creating an object of that class within {% %} or make it static somehow?

Comment: (correct me if im wrong please! I do have some programming experience but this is all new to me)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking - the Django template language needs Django to run. You can do without a database, but you still need something to turn the templates into web pages.

Comment: ah sugar i've gone about this all the wrong way! One last question, are there any alternative scripting languages that support some sort of wesbsite templatisation without any messy installation? Perl or PHP?

Answer (score 2):

[Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) is the webserver software. It's already running on their machines. Don't try and install it lol, or they will certainly laugh at you.

To "run commands" you need to get a remote shell (console). This is typically done via [Secure Shell (SSH)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). See this page regarding 123reg specifically: [How do I connect using SSH (Putty)?](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/VPS/Linux/how-do-i-connect-using-ssh-putty-3305/)

[Django supports different databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/), including SQLite and MySQL.  SQLite is typically for small, simple databases, as the "database" is really just a local file that is manipulated by the SQLite engine.  MySQL is the database of choice for many websites.

Comment: AHh i see thank you! What about mod_wsgi, is it likely to be ready installed/ up to them to install if they allow it to? Thank you for the info, what steps will be needed to utilise their version of MySql instead of SQLite?